# How to disable an object after it goes outside camera's viewport?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a gameobject at a certain position in the game. I want the gameobject to be disabled once it is outside the camera's viewport, and it should become visible only when the camera focuses at that position.

Answer (score 2):

Attach a script to the gameobject and implement the [`OnBecameVisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html) and [`OnBecameInvisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html):

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnBecameInvisible()
    {
        Debug.Log("I'm not visible anymore");
    }

    void OnBecameVisible()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hey! I'm visible!");
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that, if you **disable** the gameobject, the renderers will be disabled too, and `OnBecameVisible` won't be called.

Answer (score 1):

[Camera.WorldToViewportPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToViewportPoint.html) or WorldToScreenPoint is probably what you want. Disable the object if any coordinate if outside the "allowed" range (0-1 for viewport, 0-Screen.Width/Height for screen points). If the object is large, add a tolerance depending on size and distance.

Also, if you're just looking to improve performance, please note that [frustum culling is handled by the engine by default](https://forum.unity.com/threads/frustum-culling-by-default.48384/).